# A query for JpaRepository to pass it to controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am doing a home assignment where I have 2 classes, which are `User` and `Car`. `User` has a OneToMany relationship to `Car` entity, therefore I need to implement a controller method, which will be selecting all cars of a special user (by ID)

I guess it has something todo with `@Query` annotation in `UserRepository` which extends `JpaRepository`.
I am using a JpaRepository, which has  generics.

Example: `GET method - /users/{id}/cars`

The data should be received in JSON format smth like that:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Taavet Prulskih",
  "cars":[{
    "Id":"1",
    "make":"BMW",
    "model":"760",
    "numberplate":"123FFF"
  },
  {
    "Id":"2",
    "make":"Opel",
    "model":"Astra",
    "numberplate":"789BFX"
  }]
}
```

Question is: how does the query will be looking like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpringData query methods, just create new method in `CarRepository` like that:

```java
List<Car> findByUser_id(String id);
```

More examples in [Query methods documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: And then I just pass the @PathVariable from Controller method to the (String id) variable?

Comment: Yes. But now i see that you added example of JSON format. With my answer result will be list of cars only, like ``[{ "Id":"1", "make":"BMW", ... }, { "Id":"2", "make":"Opel", ... }]``. For your JSON format needed correct ``@OneToMany`` and ``@ManyToOne`` mapping annotations - [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships) and ``@JsonManagedReference`` and ``@JsonBackReference`` annotation for json serialization - [example](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion). After that you can find ``User`` by id and return in controller.

Comment: I got all the mapping being done and tested, the only thing for me now is that I am trying to understand how can I make it return the user by ID with list of cars inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an UserDTO like this:

```
private static class UserDTO(){
private Long id;
private String name;
private List<Cars> cars;
//getters and setters
}
```

With JPA you can get the user that you want, in your repository:

```
User findByUserId(Long id)
```

And then fill the DTO like this:

```
UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
User user = repository.findByUserId(id);
dto.setId(user.getUserId);
dto.setName(user.getName);
dto.setCars(user.getCars); //get the list of cars of the user and sets entire list to dto.cars

return dto;//finally return dto to controller
```

Comment: Do you mind to explain few more things. I have never touched DAO or DTO examples. Does UserDTo should be created in the same 'Entity' package that has a Car and User classes?
And also, do you mind providing an example of Controller? Cuz its a bit unclear still :C
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Yeap men, you can create dto in the same entity package,A dto is like and entity but only with the properties that you want, in this case is id,name and the list of cars also need to create getters and setters or just anotate the class with @data (search lombok),

Comment: `@GetMapping(value = "/users/{id}/cars")`  
 `public UserDTO getListOfCars(@PathVariable long id) {`  
 `//You can fill the dto here but its recommended to separate your classes for good practice, search for Dependency Injection Desing Pattern`   
  `return service.getListOfCars(id);`  
   `}`